# One Transaction for a set of service methods -for Rollback Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a set of service methods which has various DAO save operations.Currently my transaction advice is at service level.How would i set transaction advice to rollback the entire service methods if there is any exception in any of them.

```
    <tx:method name="saveMethod1" propagation="REQUIRED"
            rollback-for="com.demo.CustomException" />
```

I cannot have all this saveMethod1,saveMethod2,saveMethod3 operations  in one single method as there is some other logic needs to be done .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make a new service that has one method that calls all the DAOs. But if you need other logic from the existing methods then the alternative is to wrap the existing service method calls in a method (of another service, so you are calling public methods through the proxies) and make that transactional. The methods being called would have to have their transaction propagation set to REQUIRES so that they can participate in the transaction instated by the wrapping method. Since this is what you have specified anyway there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: what are the different types of Propagations ? other than SUPPORTS,REQUIRED,NEVER,REQUIRES_NEW

Comment: MANDATORY, NESTED, NOT SUPPORTED.

Comment: i had already tried with creating a new service and calling all the get,save DAO methods from this . The one  dao save method has around 10 session.save methods , but in the service layer when i check it is generating insert query only for one Table(Pojo) , weird !!!

Comment: @arbiter: agreed, something weird is going on. Without more detail in the question there's not much I can do.